# Page jumps to the top when checkbox is clicked css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a Html page where i have created a small looking button to display instead of a checkbox

```css
div label input {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#ck-button {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}

#ck-button:hover {
  background: red;
}

#ck-button label {
  float: left;
  width: 4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
}

#ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked+span {
  background-color: #911;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div id="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
```

Comment: `<div id="ck-button">` should be `<div class="ck-button">` you can not use same id

Comment: I don't think that it's that @JigarShah

Comment: Why are you using `<input>` when you are not using a `<form>`?

Comment: I'm not saying its solution of question, just giviing suggesting @funilrys

Comment: @JigarShah thanks for your reply.but output is same

Answer (score 1):

> 1) `ID` must be unique,you use `#ck-button` for more of one element.use of `class` instead of `id`.
>
> 2) Insert `position: relative;` to parent of `input`.`top:-20px;` must be measured relative to `label` no `body`.

```
.ck-button label {
  position: relative;<---------------Added
  //more codes ....
}
```

```css
div label input {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.ck-button {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
}

.ck-button:hover {
  background: red;
}

.ck-button label {
  float: left;
  width: 4.0em;
  position: relative;
  
}

.ck-button label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
}

.ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}

.ck-button input:checked+span {
  background-color: #911;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="2"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="3"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions
  have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<div class="ck-button">
  <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="4"><span>Reject</span>
       </label>
</div>
<p>
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
  et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
  1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
  versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
```

Comment: thankyewww it's working..but it's not working Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should point out you have duplicate ID's. Change `<div id="ck-button">` to `<div class="ck-button">` and change `#chk-button` to `.chk-button` in your CSS.

Also, try tweaking this CSS:

```
#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
```

Possibly absolute should actually be relative?

Answer (score 0):

As Jigar Shah points out, you should not use the same ID multiple times. Try changing it to a class instead.

The problem is with your CSS:

```
.ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}
```

Changing this to `fixed` should work as in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hck81ww/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a position:relative to "#ck-button label"  selector

```css
#ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
    position:relative;
}
```

Page jumps to the top, because inputs positioned according body tag (-20px top of body). So focus input jumps page to the top.

Adding position relative to inputs parent will fix this. Because Inputs will positioned -20px top of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kLv497m/)

```
$('label').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).find('input');
    target.each(function () { this.checked = !this.checked; })
});
```